# Combination of Apache, Tomcat, port 80, 8080 and other stuff

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy, virtualhost, forward

I have a Centos5 with running httpd, mysql and tomcat6. All fine. My goal is to achieve the following

www.domain.com  >>> forwards/proxies to www.domain.com:8080/myapplication (served by tomcat)
www.domain.com/phpmyadmin >>> www.domain.com/phpmyadmin (served by Apache from htdocs)
www.domain.com/* >>> also serverd by htdocs folder as "normal" Apache content

How can I achieve this? Any ideas?

THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only deviation from apache serving htdocs seems to be sending stuff to tomcat, which is running a servlet "myappplication". In this case,

1. Define a worker (some text string, lets call it "myworker").
2. Near the end of file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, add the lines

--Ignore this line in the post--

```
# Where to find workers.properties
# Update this path to match your conf directory location (put workers.properties next to httpd.conf)
JkWorkersFile /etc/apache2/workers.properties

# Where to put jk logs
# Update this path to match your logs directory location (put mod_jk.log next to access_log)
JkLogFile /var/log/apache2/mod_jk.log

# Set the jk log level [debug/error/info]
JkLogLevel info

# Select the log format
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "

# JkOptions indicate to send SSL KEY SIZE,
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories

# JkRequestLogFormat set the request format
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"


             JkMount /myapplication/* myworker
```

1. In that directory, create a file "workers.properties", that contains the following:

   ```
   worker.myworker.type=ajp13
   worker.myworker.host=localhost
   worker.myworker.port=8081
   worker.myworker.cachesize=10
   worker.myworker.cache_timeout=600
   worker.myworker.socket_keepalive=1
   worker.myworker.socket_timeout=300
   ```
2. Edit the line tomcat_inst_dir/conf/server.xml to put in a line

   [Connector port="8081" protocol="AJP/1.3" /]

Note: change the square brackets to angle brackets.
The above line goes inside the [service]...[/Service] tags and out of the [Engine] ... [/Engine] tags, put it right above the [Engine] line.

1. Restart apache and tomcat

Now any request to "http://www.domain.com/myapplication/servletName[?par=value...]" gets redirected by apache (on port 80) to tomcat (on port 8081) and on to the servlet myapplication. I assume you have a directory "tomcat_home/webapps/myapplication", which in turn has a directory WEB-INF with a "web.xml" file in it. "servletName" above  is what you define between the [servlet-name]...[/servlet-name] tags in that file.

I chose the number 8081 (feel free to choose your port number as long as it doesnt conflict with other standard services) so that port 8080 is still active for you to test "http://www.domain.com:8080/myapplication/servletName" (should produce same output on ports 8080 and 80, the apache port).

IMPORTANT: Keep a backup copy of all the files changed in the above process, so you can revert back to your working system if the above doesn't work. I had to go through countless iterations of the above to get it working!

Good luck, and hope this works out for you, - M.S.

PS. Sorry about the formatting - I couldnt get this any better

Comment: Hm... I just re-read your post. Wouldn't this solution require me to use www.domain.com/myapp/ as URL? Maybe a better solution could be to reoute everything to Tomcat BUT a certain list of defined urls/folders, like domain.com/phpmyadmin

Comment: With the above solution, www.domain.com/myapps/ goes to the servlet, and ...domain.com/phpmyadmin/ grabs contents of /var/www/phpmyadmin/index.html, or from wherever your default html directory is. You can have "everything" rerouted to tomcat, use "/*" in the JkMount line, but then you have to have the phpmyadmin directory inside tomcat_inst/webapps. Whether or not you have a WEB-INF directory there shouldn't matter, tomcat can serve raw html pages too, and almost as fast as apache (thats what I've read). But that might be an unnecessary redirection, IMHO. Regards, - M.S.

Comment: On another note, I assume you want some privilege/protection set up for admin web pages. If you send everything to tomcat, I am not sure if you can still use the html goodies like ".htaccess", but feel free to experiment. Later, - M.S.

Comment: I re-read your note - and may be you are asking how to get apache to forward everything to tomcat except phpmyadmin. If that is the case, sorry, I do not have an answer. Regards, - M.S.

Comment: I started to try your solution but I failed as I did not have mod_jk installed and couldn't figure out how to do that properly. I will mark answered anyways, as I guess it would have help. Thanks anyways. I will have to live with the ports in URL.

Answer (score 0):

Have your index file in www.domain.com redirect to www.domain.com:8080/myapplication.  Example index.php:

```
<?php

  header("Location: http://www.domain.com:8080/myapplication");

?>
```

Not the cleanest or most elegant way but it works.  The elegant approach would be to use vhosts in apache.

Comment: His question is ambiguous whether or not he's looking for a redirect as you suggest or a proxy like the one above.  It's much cleaner to use mod_jk to proxy and keep all requests from the user on the same port.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear: I am not looking for a redirect of the url. I also don't want the port in the URL etc. I "just" want to have my tomcat application respond to my domain requests...