# Having trouble forwarding apache to port 8080

Tags: java, php, javascript, apache, tomcat

Hey guys i'm having a bit of a problem with the setup i'm trying to get to.

I've got tomcat running on 8080 and apache2 running on 80, and i'm a bit lost as to how i can get apache to forward to tomcat for specific files. I'm setting up webgoat as a link on my apache homepage

EX:

```
127.0.0.1 -> Goes to homepage
Homepage has links to webgoat at 127.0.0.1:8080/WebGoat/attack
```

I'm trying to set this up as a home pen test server for myself, i want to trying to add as much capability and since having php work with tomcat is a bit ... Out of wack, i'd rather have php running with apache2 and then just link to tomcat for my java type files.

Thanks.

EDIT: Yes i have looked at the other questions on here from before and it seems like they aren't pertaining to the same thing i am. And the ones that did were very old.

Comment: If you look through the Related links on the right hand side, you will find tons of information for this particular topic. You might start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759523/combination-of-apache-tomcat-port-80-8080-and-other-stuff?rq=1) and work your way downwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `.htaccess` file on your apache and add:

```
# Redirect old file path to new file path
Redirect /olddirectory/oldfile.html http://example.com:8080/newdirectory/newfile.html
```

Comment: Okay i've tested that and it doesnt work.. i put the .htaccess where index.html is for apache (root /var/www) and changed it to Redirect /test.html http://127.0.0.1:8080/WebGoat/attack with no success

Comment: Try adding a 301 between `Redirect` and `/test.html`, and don't forget the `http://` in front of IP.